# Alternating layout for every odd and even page (tikz frame with text in a flowframe)

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-numbering, flowfram

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{paperwidth=29.7cm,paperheight=7cm,margin=0cm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\pechafront}{
    \newdynamicframe{29.7cm}{7cm}{0cm}{0cm}[front]
    \setdynamiccontents*{front}{
        \vfil\hfil
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[color=black,very thick] (2.7,.93) rectangle +(24.3,5.14)
            (2.77,1) rectangle +(24.16,5)
            (3.77,1) rectangle +(.07,5)
            (25.97,1) rectangle +(.07,5);
            \node[rotate=-90] at (3.2,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
            \node[rotate=90] at (26.47,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \newflowframe{21.7cm}{4.9cm}{4cm}{.9cm}[frontframe]
}

\newcommand{\pechaback}{
    \newdynamicframe{29.7cm}{7cm}{0cm}{0cm}[back]
    \setdynamiccontents*{back}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[color=black] (0,0) +(29.7,7)
            (3.77,1) rectangle +(22.16,5.12)
            (2.77,1) rectangle +(24.16,5.12);
            \node[rotate=90] at (3.43,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
            \node[rotate=-90] at (26.33,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \newflowframe{21.7cm}{4.9cm}{4.0cm}{0.9cm}[backframe]
}

\sloppy

\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
    \pechafront
\else
    \pechaback
\fi
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The pages render as if they are all odd. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm running this under LuaLaTeX

Comment: I don't use lualatex and don't know `ifoddpage` etc, but shouldn't this test be done on any page, i.e. in a page shipout hook?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have no idea. I'm learning as I'm going here. If you know anything about this, I would really appreciate some more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just specify the page list as `even` or `odd` in the optional argument when defining the dynamic frames.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{paperwidth=29.7cm,paperheight=7cm,margin=0cm}
\pagestyle{empty}


\newdynamicframe[odd]{29.7cm}{7cm}{0cm}{0cm}[front]
\setdynamiccontents*{front}{
    \vfil\hfil
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[color=black,very thick] (2.7,.93) rectangle +(24.3,5.14)
        (2.77,1) rectangle +(24.16,5)
        (3.77,1) rectangle +(.07,5)
        (25.97,1) rectangle +(.07,5);
        \node[rotate=-90] at (3.2,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
        \node[rotate=90] at (26.47,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newdynamicframe[even]{29.7cm}{7cm}{0cm}{0cm}[back]
\setdynamiccontents*{back}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[color=black] (0,0) +(29.7,7)
        (3.77,1) rectangle +(22.16,5.12)
        (2.77,1) rectangle +(24.16,5.12);
        \node[rotate=90] at (3.43,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
        \node[rotate=-90] at (26.33,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newflowframe{21.7cm}{4.9cm}{4cm}{.9cm}[myframe]

\sloppy% this is very bad - do you really need this for your entire document?

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Alternating designs]

## EDIT

Changing things for a single page is less straightforward. However, you could use `afterpage` and a bit of fiddling like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\geometry{paperwidth=29.7cm,paperheight=7cm,margin=0cm}
\pagestyle{empty}


\newdynamicframe[odd]{29.7cm}{7cm}{0cm}{0cm}[front]
\newdynamicframe[even]{29.7cm}{7cm}{0cm}{0cm}[back]
\newflowframe{21.7cm}{4.9cm}{4cm}{.9cm}[myframe]
\setdynamiccontents*{front}{
    \vfil\hfil
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[color=black,very thick] (2.7,.93) rectangle +(24.3,5.14)
        (2.77,1) rectangle +(24.16,5)
        (3.77,1) rectangle +(.07,5)
        (25.97,1) rectangle +(.07,5);
        \node[rotate=-90] at (3.2,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
        \node[rotate=90] at (26.47,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\setdynamiccontents*{back}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[color=black] (0,0) +(29.7,7)
        (3.77,1) rectangle +(22.16,5.12)
        (2.77,1) rectangle +(24.16,5.12);
        \node[rotate=90] at (3.43,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
        \node[rotate=-90] at (26.33,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\sloppy

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[3-4]
\dynamicsetpagelist{2}{none}
\dynamicsetpagelist{1}{\thepage}
\afterpage{%
  \dynamicsetpagelist{2}{even}
  \dynamicsetpagelist{1}{odd}
}
\lipsum[5-8]
\end{document}
```

[image: switched on page 2]

Comment: Thank you ever so much! That was the perfect answer. The \sloppy is very much needed unfortunately. It has to do with rendering Tibetan using the polyglossia package and XeTeX\LuaTex

Comment: Do you know of a way to manually force the "frontframe" for one page, no matter if the page is even or odd? Perhaps some macro to manually insert in my text wherever I would need to force a "frontframe".

Comment: @jollyroger No, sorry. I had one idea but it turned out to be hopelessly incompatible with reality. So I'm afraid I have no idea how you can do that except by temporarily redefining the contents of the relevant dynamic frame.

Comment: @jollyroger See my edited answer for a way to use `afterpage` to do this. Is that what you meant? Note that according to the manual, you **must** use the IDN rather than an IDL in this case.